# Setting an active profile in bootstrap.yml does not affect evaluation of application.yml. Is this a bug, or a feature I don't recognise?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I add `spring.profiles.active=DEV` in `bootstrap.yml` this is processed fine for bootstrap. I.e. the DEV profile will be loaded from the bootstrap properties. However it doesn't work when processing `application.yml`.

From stepping through the code, this seems to be due to the information about the activated profile is not pushed far enough up (only into the `StandardEnvironment`, which seems to be local to the `ConfigFileApplicationListener`. When evaluating the application.yml the environment is created from the original information again and the profile is not read.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find any documentation on that. Documentation always refers to setting this property in the `application.properties`. Now I'm curious if this is an (intended) part of the feature that might need some documentation brush up, or rather a bug that should be fixed?

Comment: I hit the same issue. When I set `spring.profiles.active: dev` on `bootstrap.yml`, I get `No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default.` It works fine when set on `application.yml`. I need to set it on `bootstrap.yml` or properties won't work on `logback-spring.xml`.

Comment: Christian Frommeyer, @Jose Armesto - did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

When combine use with spring cloud, you can set an active profile in bootstrap.yml.

Add this to you pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, it seems that this was triggered by a bug.

At least with Spring boot 2.0.3 it is possible to define active profiles within bootstrap.yml and activate profiles that are defined in application.yml

Ensure not to have double quotes around your active profiles within the yml configuration, otherwise they are not treated correctly.